# Can Illustrator art brushes rotate with a Wacom art pen or airbrush?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, drawing-tablet, wacom

The pen for my wacom tablet suffered a fatal accident while moving home, and I'm looking to replace it. Given that all Wacom accessories cost a bomb, I'm considering upgrading to an **Art Pen** or **Airbrush**, which are more expensive than the standard pen but come with the ability to detect the angle you're holding them at.

I like doing [freehand drawing in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/pressure-sensitive-freehand-drawing-of-vector-paths-that-are-editable-with-the-i), and I really like the idea that art brush artwork would rotate as my pen rotates. But is that actually how it works?

Looking at the settings, I see that you can set a **Caligraphic brush** to rotate with your pen:

[image]

...and **Scatter brushes**:

[image]

...and [Adobe's docs confirm that it works with the **Bristle brush**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html), no settings needed:

> Use the Wacom Intuos 3 or higher tablet with Art (6D) pen to explore the full capabilities of the Bristle brush. Illustrator can interpret all 6-degrees of freedom that this device combination provides.

...but I can't see anything equivalent in the art brush settings. Does this mean it automatically rotates/tilts, or never rotates and strictly follows the angle of the path? If version matters, this is CS6.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Art brushes**..... no. Art brushes (like pattern brushes) use the base path as a spine to just lie the art along.

Art brushes don't have *any* rotation dynamics at all, so there's nothing for the tablet to interact with. The brush *must* have rotation possibilities for any of the tablet features to alter them.

As far as I'm aware, only **Scatter**, **Bristle**, and **Calligraphic** brushes have rotation options. And the **Blob Brush Tool** (which is really just a calligraphic brush).

FYI.. I use the Wacom Art Pen Stylus, just because I like how it feels in the hand a bit more than the standard Grip Pen Stylus. Having the added dynamics for rotation, angle, etc. can help a great deal in Photoshop, but in Illustrator there's not a great deal of places to use all the possible dynamics the Art Pen Stylus will read. I got the Art Pen Stylus because, like you, I had to replace the stylus.. so $70 for the Grip pen or $90 for the Art Pen... I figured the $20 extra was worth a try and ended up preferring it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just curious - have you ever tried the airbrush? From what I can tell it seems to be basically just an airbrush-shaped art pen with a mouse wheel as well as the buttons?

Comment: @user568458 Never tried the airbrush. It essentially gives you dynamic control over the "flow" setting in Photoshop - no use for AI as far as I'm aware.... Just not something I've ever really thought I needed.